# How to replace/ rewrite document.forms[0].all in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

This script `var AllObjects = document.forms[0].all` is throwing error like `undefined`.

Can someone guide me how to rewrite this? Thank you

```
function SubmitTheForm(button) {
    var selectBox;
    PleaseWait();
    var AllObjects = document.forms[0].all;
    var requiredFields = document.getElementById('RequiredFieldsLabel').innerText;
    for (i = 0; i < AllObjects.length; i++) {
        if (AllObjects[i].className === 'Mandatory') {
            if (AllObjects[i].type === "text" && trim(AllObjects[i].value) === '') {
                return false;
            }
            else if ((AllObjects[i].type === "select-multiple" || AllObjects[i].type === "select-one") && AllObjects[i].style.display !== 'none' && AllObjects[i].options.length === 0)
                return false;
            }
            else if (AllObjects[i].type === "select-one" && AllObjects[i].value === "") {                 
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
function PleaseWait() {
    displayAnimationIn($("body"), "", "loading-80.gif");
}
```

Comment: if you want to get all `input` elements, you could do `var AllObjects = document.forms[0].getElementsByTagName("input");`

Comment: @GrafiCode, could you please tell me what this line does `document.forms[0].all`

Comment: as far as I know, there's no `.all` property / method for `form` elements, so  this `document.forms[0].all` gives null